Resolving merge conflict & Automatically marking PR as remotely merged
Trying to understand why it works.
Pre-Req:  Branch creation: Main -> New Release Branch (release/2024-12-12) - > New feature Branch (feature/NewMenu)
I add my changes to feature/NewMenu. Raise a PR from feature/NewMenu -> develop Where I'm asked to resolve the merge conflicts, since other developer would have merged their feature branch to develop branch.
I follow below steps in git console:

git branch o/p shows : feature/NewMenu

git pull

git checkout develop

git pull

git merge feature/NewMenu o/p: shows auto-merge conflicts I resolve
the conflicts.

git checkout -b mergefix/Resolved

git add & commit

git push


When PR is merged from mergefix/Resolved to develop. The other conflicted PR is not marked as remotely merged.
If I modify the last 3 steps it works as expected:

git add & commit
git checkout -b mergefix/Resolved.
git push

Why does this work? What is the difference ?

I am under the impression that you are not doing it correctly. You are merging your feature branch into your local develop branch. This is probably a no-go as you are keeping local commits in develop that are not in the remote one.... but anyway, moving forward with what you provided, then, the local feature branch does not get that merge and so whatever you push in the last line does not include it either.

Actually, I think you are missing wrapping up the merge between these two steps, if you got a conflict: git merge feature/NewMenu o/p; git checkout -b mergefix/Resolved. But anyway, that does not change my previous comment.

It sounds like the assumption is that the resulting state is identical, and the only difference between the two is whether you first create the merge commit on develop and then create a new branch, or, you fist make a new branch and then create the merge commit. From Git's POV, the result should be identical. From BB's POV, the first push of the new branch is also identical. So something else must be different. Are you pushing the merge commit on develop accidentally? What about the merge commit messages? (I doubt BB cares about the merge commit messages, but at least it's something...)

No, I'm not pushing the merge commit on develop.

Below is the answer is received from BitBucket community:

Original steps

In the original steps you are creating a new branch mergefix/Resolved after resolving conflicts and then committing your changes only to this new branch.
When you create a new branch, Git uses the current HEAD as the base for that branch. Hence, when you create mergefix/Resolved, it is based on the develop branch after resolving the merge, and your commit containing conflict resolutions is only on this new branch.
However, because the conflicts were resolved and committed after switching to a new branch, Git does not recognize the original merge as having been completed on the develop branch. It essentially sees the conflict resolution as a separate line of development from the initial merge attempt from feature/NewMenu.

Modified steps

On the other hand, in the modified sequence, you resolve conflicts and commit the changes while still on the develop branch before creating the new branch mergefix/Resolved. When you commit after resolving conflicts on the develop branch, Git records the merge as having been completed on develop. Creating the branch mergefix/Resolved afterward is suitable for pushing and raising a PR, but it does not affect how the merge commit itself is perceived.
The modified steps work as expected because the merge resolution is committed directly on the develop branch. This allows Git to recognize that the conflict from feature/NewMenu to develop has been resolved.
